quantization using ONNX model. inference step
I am having some trouble with ONNX quantization.
I converted a ResNet18 into an ONNX quantized model and I am trying to implement some dedicated hardware to replicate the operations. In the quantization step, on the ONNX reference it is explained that for quantization the formula is:
y = saturate ((x / y_scale) + y_zero_point).
and for de-quantization the formula is:
y = (x - x_zero_point) * x_scale
I am using symmetric quantization (zero_point=0), so it becomes just:
quantization:
y = saturate (x / y_scale) .
de-quantization:
y = x * x_scale
you can find informations about this here
https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/performance/model-optimizations/quantization.html
the issue is that if I look at the scaling factors that are calculated during the calibration step, after training, by ONNX, the scaling factors are all smaller than one. for instance they are values between 0 and 1.  this is shown in the attached picture (generate with Netron).
example of ONNX scale factor for quantization 
if my scaling factor is smaller than one, then the quantization and de-quantization operations do not make sense anymore. Because supposing I want to quantize in int8, and I start from fp32 numbers, I would like to have something like:
xq = x_fp /s
so than I can reduce the dinamic range of the x_fp to be represented in int8. but if my scaling factor is smaller than one, I am acually expanding the range !
so for quantization I get a bigger range instead of smaller, and for de-quantize I get a smaller range, instead of bigger.
I was thinking that I might have to multiply the scaling factor by my desired quantization bit width, such as 2^8=256 for uint8.
since the scaling factor is calculated as s= (2^N-1) / fp_range, they might provide only the part:
s_onnx = 1/fp_range
and leave to you the multiplication of a desired bit with precision.
can someone help me about this ?
thank you !
considering that the scaling factors are between 0 and 1, then I would expect a formula like this:
quantization
x_q = x_fp * scale
de-quantize
x_fp = x_q / scale
instead of the opposite.
